# VSCode terminal colors are screwed

Tags: visual-studio-code, zsh

I am using iterm2  with powerlevel10k font and a color theme.
For example, the green color in my iterm2 is showing in vscode integrated terminal as grey.

Why are they not the same? and how can I make them the same?
Below are few terminal settings of my vscode

```
{
    "terminal.external.osxExec": "iTerm.app",
    "terminal.integrated.shell.osx": "/bin/zsh",
    "terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "MesloLGS NF"
}
```

**iTerm2:**
[image]

**VSCode integrated terminal:**
[image]

Comment: The easiest way is to change your color scheme to be dark. If you want the colors to match iTerm2 perfectly, or you prefer keeping the editor's light color scheme, you can follow this tutorial to customize terminal colors (just copy color strings one by one from your iTerm2 settings): https://mybyways.com/blog/vs-code-override-terminal-color-theme